# Update Mysql value from an <a href> link uncaught referenceError

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and mysql and am having problems understanding why a specific function to update a value within the databse isnt working.

I want to be able to change a "0" int to a "1" when the user clicks the link.  (I am using the value 0 / 1 to track if the user account is active or not).

The link in question reads:

```
<?php

    $user = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

    //check to see if the user is active or not
    if ($user [0]['active'] == 0)
    {
    printf("Your account is not currently active ");
    printf('<a href="#" onclick="activate();">Click Me</a>');
    printf(" to reactivate");
    }
    //assuming they have logged in they will probably want to make themselves active

?>
```

When I click the link the console reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: activate is not defined
```

I have defined activate in a separate functions.php file that is being loaded and has the correct permissions. (I am sure it is being loaded by the code above as when I define activate manually in the code above the I get an error telling me I cannot define 2 functions with the same name).

The functions.php section reads:

```
function activate()
    {
    require("../templates/activate_user.php");
    exit;
    }
```

Finally, the activate_user.php reads:

```
<?php
    // configuration
        require("../includes/config.php"); 

    query("UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
    return false;

?>
```

I have searched and searched on how to fix this error, but I have not been able to fix the issue.  I am guessing it might be related to scope of activate, but am not sure that is the right path.

Any help well received, this is my first venture into php/mysql so all points welcome.

Thanks;

Andy

Comment: You mixed php and js. You cannot call activate() php function from js directly. Use AJAX to request php file.

Comment: You cannot call PHP functions from JavaScript. You could try doing an AJAX-call to access the function. Also, why do you just require the actual function inside your `function activate()`? Just put the code from `activate_user.php` into your function.

Comment: Phantom - so is the error in the functions.php? Or should I be looking to use AJAX from the original a href link to call the function?  Sorry, I havent used AJAX before so am trying to work out where to tailor my google searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of keeping things simple I have solved the problem by calling the same page and defining the function within that page:

```
<?php

function activate()
    {
    require("../templates/activate_user.php");
    exit;
    }

//check to see if the user is active or not
    if ($user [0]['active'] == 0)
    {
    printf("Your account is not currently active ");
    printf('<a href="index.php?action=callfunction">Click Me</a>');
    printf(" to reactivate");

    //assuming they have logged in they will probably want to make themselves active
    if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] =='callfunction'){
    activate();
    }

    }
?>
```

Not sure if its pretty or not, but it certainly works.  Thanks for the help and comments (made searching much easier!)

Answer (score 0):

The onclick="activate();" is Javascript code. The rest of your code is written in PHP. Both won't work together this way.